# Starting from Xcode 14, resource bundles are signed by default, which requires setting the development team for each resource bundle target

Tags: xcode, expo, eas

I am getting the following error when making an expo EAS IOS build. with

```
eas build --platform ios
```

> Starting from Xcode 14, resource bundles are signed by default, which
> requires setting the development team for each resource bundle target.
> To resolve this issue, downgrade to an older Xcode version using the
> "image" field in eas.json, or turn off signing resource bundles in
> your Podfile: https://expo.fyi/r/disable-bundle-resource-signing

How can I resolve this error?